# MYSQL return list of row IDs which are not present in other database tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on merging an old database into a new one. In the new database I have four database tables:  `'task_clone', 'potential_task', 'task'` and `'task_archive'`.

`'task_clone'` contains all the database entries of type task imported from the older database and I'm trying to distribute these entries across the other three tables in the new database. `'task_clone'` is therefore a temporary table.

`'task_clone'` contains 649 entries. The structure of the data does not map very easily to the new database and after copying the rows from `'task_clone'` the sum total of the other three tables entries is 566, which means there are 83 entries in `'task_clone'` that have yet to be mapped into the new structure.

I'm trying to query `'task_clone'` to figure out which entries are in the other three tables that are not in `'task_clone'`.

All three tables contain the column `'task_id'`, which is unique id for each task entry. I should therefore be able to query the database and get all the `'task_id'` columns in `'task_clone'` returning the entires that do not match those in the other three tables.

I know this should be possible in a single query but I can't quite seem to get the syntax correct. Where am I going wrong and how should this be written? I initially tried:

```
SELECT task_clone.task_id 
FROM task_clone 
WHERE 
    task_clone.task_id != potential_task.task_id 
    AND task_clone.task_id != task.task_id 
    AND task_clone.task_id != task_archive.task_id;
```

I also looked at some other approaches to doing this with two tables (i.e. returning values from one that were not in the other) but I couldn't find an example that I could translate cleanly into a solution that would work for more than two tables without getting error messsages. Thanks for reading.

NOTE in response to this being marked as a duplicate:  This question is not a duplicate of those previous questions which ask specifically about two tables since my question specially enquires about working with four tables. The solution supplied on the cited question, while using roughly the same syntax, does not provide a solution to the question of 4 tables. Further, in my question I clearly state that I've looked at previous stack answers that deal with two tables and I couldn't translate them to four without getting error messages.

Comment: Hint: `... table1  LEFT JOIN table2 WHERE table1.column IS NULL` or simply `... table 1 WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table2)`

Comment: yes but that's two tables, not four.

Comment: if that not solving it i advice you to provice example data and expected results.. i advice you to read this [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) into providing it

Comment: Thanks for that Raymond. I was not aware of that advice on meta. I thought the issue was not so much based on the structure of the database but the structure of the query hence posting only the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from one table where not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596073/select-from-one-table-where-not-in-another)

Comment: Did whoever marked this as a duplicate read the question? I clearly state I’ve looked at approaches that use two tables. I couldn’t find and example that translates into a solution for four. Other people will have this problem and people need to stop marking questions on this forum as ‘possible duplicate’ when questions have a similar common basis, as the solutions required may be different, as may the solutions presented by people answering. Do people get status points for this or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use NOT IN?

```
 SELECT task_clone.task_id FROM task_clone 
 WHERE task_clone.task_id NOT IN  (SELECT task_id from potential_task)
 AND task_clone.task_id NOT IN  (SELECT task_id from task)
 AND task_clone.task_id NOT IN  (SELECT task_id from task_archive)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I was not aware of the NOT IN clause. Thanks you. It wont let me click accept right now. I keep getting a message saying you can accept in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `task_id` is a primary key in all tables, the `LEFT JOIN` approach seems more efficient and concise :

```
SELECT tc.*
FROM 
    task_clone tc
    LEFT JOIN potential_task pt ON pt.task_id = tc.task_id
    LEFT JOIN task t ON t.task_id = tc.task_id
    LEFT JOIN task_archive ta ON ta.task_id = tc.task_id
WHERE
    pt.task_id     IS NULL 
    AND t.task_id  IS NULL 
    AND ta.task_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT tc.task_id
FROM task_clone tc
WHERE NOT EXiSTS (SELECT 1 FROM potential_task pt WHERE pt.task_id = tc.task_id) AND
      NOT EXiSTS (SELECT 1 FROM task t WHERE t.task_id = tc.task_id) AND
      NOT EXiSTS (SELECT 1 FROM task_archive ta WHERE ta.task_id = tc.task_id) ;
```

I much prefer `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` with subqueries because the latter does not handle `NULL`s in an intuitive manner.  If *any* `task_id` in any of the tables is `NULL`, then the outer query will return no rows at all.  This is consistent with what `NULL` means in SQL, but it is counter-intuitive.

`NOT EXISTS` treats `NULL`s as you would expect -- they don't match on a given row but they don't affect results in other rows.